# One query to get data out of 2 tables in mysql (with php)

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I have a table1 witch contains my main profile data.

Then I have table2 witch contains names(and type) of my custom user created fields (My admins can create custom fields for the main profile if they need)

And I have table3 that contains the values for the custom fields in table2. So table 3 refers to table2 for the field name and is linked to the table1 entry.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `numero_membre` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `membre` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
    (...ALOT OF FIELDS, I DONT FEEL THE NEED TO SHOW THEM ALL)
  `ordering` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dateModified` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `nom` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `type` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `published` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `ordering` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `datemodified` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `datecreated` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `table3` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idchamps` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `idprofil` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY( `id` )
);
```

So i want to SELECT all rows in table1 and i want it to join the name from table2 and make its value = from table3 that corresponds.

I was thinking LEFT JOIN. but that would seem to just add like all my table2 field names to the table1... This is complex... i hope you all understand.

If its not possible in 1 query... I think i have an alternative to get the data but this would make my life sooo much easier...

---

Objective: the User has an export data form. This form he can choose the fields from table1 and table2 that he wants for each entry (with checkboxes). then they can provide filters for ANY given field. such as `id=1` or `name LIKE %Somthing%` to filters the results.

The checkbox values are saved in addfield[]
$this->getFields() returns ALL the fields so it can loop threw the filter post values.

HERE IS MY CODE THAT generates the SQL (part of a class):

```
function getExportObject() {
    // --> FOR EXPORT
    //Building Query
    $postdata   =   JRequest::get( 'post' );
    $exportFields           = $postdata['addfield'];        //Table 1
    $exportCustomFields = $postdata['addcfield'];       //table 2 name, table 3 value
    $sqlSelect = '';
    //Main profil Fields...
    foreach($exportFields as $key => $field) {
        if ($sqlSelect!='') $sqlSelect .= ', ';
        $sqlSelect .= '`'.$field.'`';
    }

    //Add filters to the SELECT
    //GET LIST OF ALL FIELDS....
    $sqlFilter  = '';
    $loopFields = $this->getFields();
    foreach($loopFields as $key => $field) {
        if (JRequest::getVar('filter_'.$field)!='') {
            if ($sqlFilter=='') { $sqlFilter .= " WHERE "; }
            else { $sqlFilter .= " AND "; }

            switch(JRequest::getVar('filter_'.$field)) {
                case 'EQUAL'                : $sqlFilter .= "`".$field."`='".JRequest::getVar('filter_val_'.$field)."'"; break;
                case 'NOT_EQUAL'        : $sqlFilter .= "`".$field."`!='".JRequest::getVar('filter_val_'.$field)."'"; break;
                case 'CONTAINS'         : $sqlFilter .= "`".$field."` LIKE '%".JRequest::getVar('filter_val_'.$field)."%'"; break;
                case 'NOT_CONTAINS' : $sqlFilter .= "`".$field."` NOT LIKE '%".JRequest::getVar('filter_val_'.$field)."%'"; break;
                default                         : die('Utilisation invalid. SVP. essayez de nouveau.'); break;
            }
        }
    }
    //PUTTING IT ALL TOGETTHER
    //"SELECT t1.*, t2.nom, t3.value FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table3 t3 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.fieldname = t2.nom ON t1.id = t3.idprofil"
    $query = "SELECT ".$sqlSelect." FROM `table1`".$sqlFilter;
    echo $query;
    exit();
    $this->_db->setQuery($query);
    $exportList = $this->_db->loadObjectList();
    return $exportList;
} //End of getExportObject()
```

So that function works for getting the values for the table1. i havnt set any of the code for the table2. but lets say table 2 varibles are held in the same way as table 1 but in the post varibale addcfield[]

Comment: Missing some context here, I think. Can you describe what the result set you're after would look like (in an ideal world)?

Comment: how are tables1 and table2 related? does table3.idprofile=table2.id? is the primary key in table3 correct? can you give an example of what you'd like to get back?

Comment: How about using UNION to draw on multiple queries?

Comment: yes table3 the idprofile = table1.id

Comment: im making a export csv file. i need 1 array that contains all table 1 fileds + the table2.name = table3=value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand the relationship between `table2` and `table3`, but I think you're looking for something like this:

**EDIT**: Modified query based on feedback in comments. Assuming the table2 id is added to table3.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.nom, t3.value
    FROM table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN table3 t3
            INNER JOIN table2 t2
                ON t3.table_2_id = t2.id
            ON t1.id = t3.idprofil
```

Comment: table2 holds the name of the field for the value held in table3

Comment: @StiGMaT How are `table2` and `table3` related to each other? I made a best guess in my answer.

Comment: here is a value for fieldname for example: custom_1_28# the 1 = the id of table2. i think im gona add a new field to table 3 to have a plain id towards table2... my `fieldname` is bacily the name of the input when its on the form

Comment: im trying to see if i can manage to do somethign with this example you gave me. its looks like it could work. ill let you know in a bit. thanks for now

Comment: this seem too complicated... i'm think i'm just gona resort to more than 1 query.. i have WHERE clauses for values ither in table1 or table3. and its pretty damn complex...

Comment: i added alot of extra code to show where im going... so you know